# Unexpected width in shopify draggable element

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, draggable

I made a simple draggable list, using the [shopify draggable plugin](https://shopify.github.io/draggable/)

```
  <ul id="myList">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
```

```
ul {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  margin: 5px;
  background: salmon;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  cursor: move;
}
```

For some reason, when dragging, the dragged item's width gets much greater than the original item's. I suspect it's because I set the width in percentages and that it gets taken out of the parent container, so the percentage reference changes. I made a jsfiddle demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/x3jmkysq/1/

I would like it to work more like this example:
https://shopify.github.io/draggable/examples/simple-list.html
but I don't know how exactly they achieved it.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, I found the solution here:
https://github.com/Shopify/draggable/issues/147

Basically there is a property to calculate the dimensions of the dragged element from the original one called constrainDimensions.

Comment: Yes, there is a demo of your solution https://jsfiddle.net/rk8egpsz/3